# Override eclipse Plugin in Project explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

In my project the user sees the red cross icon on the file containing an error and the folders above. When the (modelling nature of the sirius) plugin is added to the project the red cross dissapears on the file (not on the folders).
How can i keep the error icon on the file?

I can get information about the content extension which probably causes the problem

```
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();         ProjectExplorer expl = (ProjectExplorer) page.findView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);            
INavigatorContentService content = expl.getNavigatorContentService();                   
INavigatorContentExtension siriusext = content.getContentExtensionById("org.eclipse.sirius.ui.resource.content.session");
siriusext.getDescriptor().getAppearsBeforeId();
```

The problem is probably the sirius INavigatorContentService because it is set to appear before id "org.eclipse.jdt.java.ui.javaContent"
(siriusext.getDescriptor().getAppearsBeforeId())

How can i (have the modelling nature and) keep the error icon on the file?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I answered your question on the Sirius forum [1].

The problem seems to come from the getImage() implementation in the label provider used by the INavigatorExtension provided by Sirius.

A workaround could be to try to provide your own navigator content with an Override element targeting the Sirius Content Management (org.eclipse.sirius.ui.resource.content.session) as suppressed extension and provide your own label provider (which could extend the Sirius one and specifically handle the file case in getImage, but you might loose the M decorator on files handled by Sirius).

Could you open a bugzilla [2] to track the issue ? Then the team will have the possibility to analyze the issue and try to find a proper solution.

Regards,

Maxime

[1] https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=877968&goto=1498330&#msg_1498330
[2] https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=sirius